# Fire different function based on what element was clicked

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two next and previous buttons that correctly call the relevant function on click. However, I need to give the parent a transitionend listener that fires different functions based on what button was clicked.

My code is:

```
      this.next = this.story.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      this.prev = this.story.nextSibling;
      this.next.addEventListener('click', evt => this.nextButton(evt));
      this.prev.addEventListener('click', evt => this.prevButton(evt));
      this.story.addEventListener('transitionend', evt => this.moveBack(evt));
```

This works correctly when pressing the next button (as the "moveBack" function triggers the slide move). I don't know how to trigger this for the previous button but to fire the function "moveForward"

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a working snippet so we can reproduce this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple way would be to store current animation direction in a variable:

```
  this.next = this.story.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  this.prev = this.story.nextSibling;
  this.next.addEventListener('click', evt => { this.dir = 'next'; this.nextButton(evt); });
  this.prev.addEventListener('click', evt => { this.dir = 'prev'; this.prevButton(evt); });
  this.story.addEventListener('transitionend', evt => {
    if(this.dir === 'next') {
       this.moveBack(evt);
    } else {
       this.moveForward(evt);
    }
  );
```